# What is the relationship between my brother in law's (sister's husband) cousin nephew to me?

Tags: meaning

Currently I am dating my brother in law's cousin sister's son. Means his cousin nephew. Family is saying he is my nephew too.. so I am wondering if this relation is legit in all terms

Comment: There is no short description of this convoluted relationship in English (and even what some other languages might call "cousin nephew" could be "first cousin once removed" in English for those who are pedantic, while "cousin sister's son" makes no sense to me).

Comment: You could marry your sister's brother-in-law, and your children would be double cousins. You're not related.

Comment: Surely his cousin's sister is also his cousin? Not that it makes any difference; he is not your blood relation.

Comment: Seems you're not asking for language but for DNA permission and responses to the judges in your family. The fact that we have no labels for such remote non-blood relations tells you there is no danger for starting your family.

Comment: You are not related to people whom you are not related to. Therefore, we have no word for those people. Why would we? After all, without consanguinity you are nothing to each other's genes.